# Zend log/mail missing some emails

Tags: php, email, zend-framework

a have a difficulty with Zend Mail/Log. But most probably with Zend Mail. It looks to me that I'm missing some important info about sending emails with Zend Mail. It would be great if you could give me some hint what is going on.

So what is the problem:

I have two actions: register and login.

In register I first log that there is a new account like this:

```
$message = 'New Account: Email: ' . $email;                    
$logger->warn($message);
```

I have a quite complex logging to db file and to mail. If the priority is equal or higher to WARN, I send email. But back to the register action.

After logging I put new account into db and at the end of action I send email to user like this:

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail('UTF-8');
$mail->setFrom(bla@bla.com);
$mail->setReplyTo(bla@bla.com);
$mail->addTo(user_email);
$mail->setSubject($subject);
$mail->setBodyText($message);
$mail->send();
```

That is all for register. Now the login action. There is just log, no email to user, so something like this:

```
$message = "Login: $email";
$logger->warn($message);
```

That is all for login.

And the problem is that I never receive a log email from register action. I can find the log in db and also in file, but the mail is not sent.

I'm lost but I'm suspecting that the problem could be when sending more than one email in one action.

Any help very appreciated,

David

**UPDATE**

- I have found that I have this problem in all actions where is logging via mail + mail to user
- I have found this in apache error log: PHP Warning:  unable to send log entries via email; message = No connection has been established to "public IP of the server with application"; code = 0; exception class = Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception in /usr/local/share/ZendFramework-1.11.6/library/Zend/Log/Writer/Mail.php on line 410
- at 410 in /usr/local/share/ZendFramework-1.11.6/library/Zend/Log/Writer/Mail.php, there is:

  ```
  try {
      $this->_mail->send();
  } catch (Exception $e) {
      trigger_error(
          "unable to send log entries via email; " .
              "message = {$e->getMessage()}; " .
              "code = {$e->getCode()}; " .
                  "exception class = " . get_class($e),
          E_USER_WARNING);
  }
  ```

Comment: Is `from` set to a valid E-Mail address that runs on the server/domain you're sending this from?

Comment: from is set correctly, bla@bla.com is just example. from is set to the same address in login and in register action

Comment: I have found that I have one more action where is logging to mail + mail to user and also log email is never send. So the problem really could when sending multiple emails per action.

Comment: I have found this in apache error log: PHP Warning:  unable to send log entries via email; message = No connection has been established to "IP of the server where is the application running"; code = 0; exception class = Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception in /usr/local/share/ZendFramework-1.11.6/library/Zend/Log/Writer/Mail.php on line 410